# Aleph null to the power of 1 is equal to Aleph null

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am working through a question on computing cardinals, and I came across this. I want to check that this is the correct way to solve this.

$\aleph_0^1=\aleph_0$, where $\aleph_0 = |\mathbb{N}|$

I can say that $\aleph_0^1 = |\mathbb{N}^1|$

Using this I can say there exists function that maps 1 to all the natural numbers, $\phi: 1 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

This function is injective, since for $a,b\in {1}$,  $f(a)=f(b)\;\implies \; a=b \;$ (clearly true since a=b is always true)

This function is surjective, since $\forall \; n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists\; 1 \in 1 \implies f(1)=n \; $ (Clearly true, since 1 maps to all $\mathbb{N}$

The function is bijective, as it is a surjective and injective function, and thus $ |\mathbb{N}^1| \sim |\mathbb{N}|$

Therefore $\aleph_0^1 = \aleph_0$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Using this I can say there exists function that maps $1$ to all the natural numbers, $\phi:1\to\Bbb N$". Could you please write it with proper quantifiers and in unambiguous fashion?

Comment: If you are talking about some function $\phi : \{1\} \to \Bbb{N}$ then there is no way that such a function could be surjective.

Comment: I'm not great at writing these sort of things out, that is why I am asking. I suppose I should be saying 'I can make a function', instead of 'using this ect', although I don't know what you mean by the proper quantifiers

Comment: You want to show that there are $\aleph_0$ functions $\phi:1\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ don't you?

Comment: Yes, I think that is a better way of wording my question